# When trying to use dependency injection and the IDisposable interface correctly should I inject an instance of SafeHandle? C#

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, tdd, idisposable

According to MSDN the best way to implement the IDisposable interface involves using an instance of the SafeHandle class.

In the [given example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx) they have the following line;

```
SafeHandle handle = new SafeFileHandle(IntPtr.Zero, true);
```

I have been reading about dependency injection and TDD and my understanding is that in order to both follow TDD and implement the IDisposable interface correctly I would have do something like this;

```
public class SomeDisposableClass : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Stream _stream;
    private readonly IDisposable _safeHandle;

    public SomeDisposableClass(Stream stream, IDisposable safeHandle)
    {
        _stream = stream;
        _safeHandle = safeHandle;
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed) return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            _safeHandle.Dispose();
            _stream.Dispose();
        }

        disposed = true;
    }
}
```

I am injecting my safeHandle instead of instantiating it within SomeDisposableClass. This would allow me to pass in a mock and assert that its Dispose method is called in the event that a SomeDisposableClass instance has its Dispose() method called.

Is this the correct thing to do when using TDD and Dependency injection or am I taking things too far? (i.e. is it OK to instantiate certain classes rather than injecting them or should I avoid "new" like the plague?)

I am aware that there are problems with my example (for example you are not obliged to pass in a SafeHandle instance, only an IDisposable instance).

Comment: Why do you think you should inject the handle, rather than create it in the class? And what's this got to do with TDD?

Comment: My understanding of TDD is that I can't write code till I have a failing test and I should only write the minimum amount of code to pass the test. If I stick to this then I don't see how I can create the handle because I cannot write a test to assert that the handle is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use DI to provide a `SafeHandle` to your class.  The `SafeHandle` is an internal implementation detail in your class, that it uses to implement `IDisposable`.  Users of your class shouldn't have to know about this internal implementation.  DI is intended to provide your class with external entities that your class collaborates with.  Don't be afraid to use `new` for objects that are used only within your class.

A really good resource is the book: http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/ I can't describe the whole book here but here's a couple of ideas. They talk about "values" and "objects".

> Values are immutable instances that model fixed quantities. Objects
>   ... use mutable state to model their behavior over time.

The style described in this book uses DI to connect a web of "objects" that collaborate with each other and uses mock objects to test these collaborations.  On the other hand, "values" are created with `new` when needed in both production and test code and passed as parameters and return values.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your answer (+1) it is very helpful. If you could elaborate on how to reconcile how you can use "new" when practicing TDD (and why it's OK to do so) or even point me in the right direction I'd certainly mark this as the correct answer. I agree that a user shouldn't have to know about internal implementation, but SafeHandle is abstract and the user may wish to pass a particular implementation e.g. based on the stream type in the given example.

Comment: The purpose of a disposable class is to encapsulate some unmanaged resource - the disposable class owns that resource and manages its lifetime, by creating a SafeHandle and calling Dispose on the SafeHandle. In your example, the class is passed a Stream, which implies that the caller of the class owns the Stream and the caller should be responsible for its lifetime.  This is why I don't think you should pass a SafeHandle into a class